# Is it possible to add just Date in a datetime column and not get appended 00:00.000

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

MY Table consists of a datetime column and I wanted to know if its possible to add just Date in the column without getting appended zeros in Time part. Currently I used 
`CONVERT(date, getdate())` and tried to insert , but it comes in as
 2013-01-20 00:00:00.000 in the column.
Pardon me if this is a very basic question

Comment: You need to change your data type to Date -- if not, it's going to store as DateTime.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is. Use the `DATE` data type instead of `DATETIME`.

However do not concern yourself with whether the 0s are there are not - that's not how SQL Server stores it internally, it's just how Management Studio is presenting it to you.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using SQL Server you could use the Date type rather than DateTime. Otherwise the zeros will be there for the time portion. Of course you can choose not to display the time portion in your application if desired.